# Date 6 months into the future

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, python-datetime

I am using the datetime Python module in django. I am looking to calculate the date if the expiry date is less than or equal to 6 months  from the current date.

The reason I want to generate a date 6 months from the current date is to set an alert that will highlight the field/column in which that event occurs. I dont know if my question is clear. I have been reading about timedelta function but cant really get my head round it. I am trying to write an if statement to statisfy this condition. Anyone able to help me please? Am a newbie to django and python.

Answer (score 10):

There are two approaches, one only slightly inaccurate, one inaccurate in a different way:

- Add a `datetime.timedelta()` of 365.25 / 2 days (average year length divided by two):

  ```
    import datetime
    sixmonths = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=365.25/2)
  ```

  This method will give you a datetime stamp 6 months into the future, where we define 6 monhs as exactly half a year (on average).
- Use the external [`dateutil` library](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/), it has a excellent [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) class that will add 6 months based on calendar calculations to your current date:

  ```
    import datetime
    from dateutil.relativedelat import relativedelta
    sixmonths = datetime.datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=6)
  ```

  This method will give you a datetime stamp 6 months into the future, where the month component of the date has been forwarded by 6, and it'll take into account month boundaries, making sure not to cross them. August 30th plus 6 months becomes February 28th or 29th (leap years permitting), for example.

A demonstration could be helpful. In my timezone, at the time of posting, this translates to:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 18, 12, 16, 0, 547567)
>>> now + datetime.timedelta(days=365.25/2)
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 20, 3, 16, 0, 547567)
>>> now + relativedelta(months=6)
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 18, 12, 16, 0, 547567)
```

So there is a 1 day and 15 hour difference between the two methods.

The same methods work fine with `datetime.date` objects too:

```
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2013, 2, 18)
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=365.25/2)
datetime.date(2013, 8, 19)
>>> today + relativedelta(months=6)
datetime.date(2013, 8, 18)
```

The half-year timedelta becomes a teensy less accurate when applied to dates only (the 5/8th day component of the delta is ignored now).

Comment: Nice suggestion about the 365.25 / 2 approach.

Comment: Should have read your post before I posted - didn't notice you used `dateutil` - oh well! :) Great post, well explained :)

Comment: well, nice one. updated link: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil

Answer (score 2):

If by "6 months" you mean 180 days, you can use:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date.today()
d + datetime.timedelta(6 * 30)
```

Alternatively if you, mean actual 6 months by calendar you'll have to lookup the [calendar module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) and do some lookups on each month. For example:

```
import datetime
import calendar

def add_6_months(a_date):
    month = a_date.month - 1 + 6
    year = a_date.year + month / 12
    month = month % 12 + 1
    day = min(a_date.day,calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1])
    return datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) a look a serious look. It is built on top of `dateutil` and `pytz` to do what you asked would simply be the following.

```
>>> d =  Delorean()
>>> d
Delorean(datetime=2013-02-21 06:00:21.195025+00:00, timezone=UTC)
>>> d.next_month(6)
Delorean(datetime=2013-08-21 06:00:21.195025+00:00, timezone=UTC)
```

It takes into account all the dateutil calculations as well as provide and interface for timezone shifts. to get the needed datetime  simple `.datetime` on the Delorean object.

Answer (score -1):

this might work for you in case you want to get an specfic date back:

```
from calendar import datetime

datetime.date(2019,1,1).strftime("%a %d")
#The arguments here are: year, month, day and the method is there to return a formated kind of date - in this case - day of the week and day of the month.
```

The outcome would be:
Tue 01

Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer does not really address a large part of the question asked

Comment: Hey  Marcucciboy2, fair point. I just put an option to be considered between the other options presented before. Cheers, mate!